# What is a "show" in petroleum geology?

Tags: geology, terminology, petroleum, gas

Is a *show* when naturally ocurring oil seeps out of a fracture on the surface? Or is it when engineers fracture rocks in order to extract oil?

Comment: Shouldn't this be in Engineering SE?

Comment: It related to petroleum geology too.

Comment: Your question is too brief to support that. Please expand the question with some more information, maybe an example or two of its use in science.

Comment: Spencer, please allow others that are more informed about the subject to make the call on whether this question (and others on the subject) belong here. The question is well-posed within the common terminology used in the field.

Answer (score 4):

A *show* is a visual indication of hydrocarbons, in the jargon of petroleum exploration, it is typically used to describe a drilling. It could be e.g. a *Gas show* in the drilling fluid. [Show evaluation](http://wiki.aapg.org/Show_evaluation) is an important tool to understand a reservoir.

When hydrocarbons reach the surface naturally, we call it a [petrolium seep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petroleum_seep).

Technically, I guess, a *seep* could be a *show* if it's used to map a [play](http://www.glossary.oilfield.slb.com/Terms/p/play.aspx) but I never heard the term used in that context.

Comment: Please show some indication of this term's use in science.

Comment: https://scholar.google.com.au/scholar?start=0&q=%22petroleum+shows%22&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5

Comment: In your answer.

Comment: There are further links with examples in the AAPG article, linked in the answer. I can't see why petroleum geology isn't Earth science. The question is about terminology, and the vocabulary used by petroleum geologists, geochemists and geophysicists might sound outlandish for people not working in the field. However, scientists in academia and industry all over the world are talking about and writing about e.g. *shows*, *seeps* and *plays*. That the word *show* have plenty of different meanings doesn't invalidate OP's question.